# Enabling "Sync All Photos" on Android App

Tags: ubuntu-one

I think this issue will be pretty easy to solve. I just re-discovered Ubuntu One Files on Android and installed it.

On the first run, I selected "Sync all photos from now on" as opposed to syncing all the photos on the sdcard.

Now I want to sync all the photos (on wifi) but can't seem to get the option back. Reinstalled several times and cleared "settings" through the stock Android app manager.

Comment: I have a similar problem. I turn off the sync option, took some pictures and turned the option back on and the pictures taken while the sync option was off are not being uploaded, there's no way to re-sync everything, except duplicates

Answer (score 1):

You can manually add file, folders and photos to Ubuntu One (the little plus at the top right.

Also in settings you can configure and force auto upload.

Does that help?

Answer (score 0):

[Ubuntu One files was shut down in 2014.](https://blog.ubuntu.com/2014/04/02/shutting-down-ubuntu-one-file-services)

This is no longer possible.